# How to import JSON in TypeScript with object destructuring?

Tags: json, typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, tslint

In a Vue project, I am trying to import a JSON module with object destructuring in TypeScript (.vue file):

```
import { logo } from '@src/config/branding.json'
```

but I get the error in VSCode: `Module ''*.json'' has no exported member 'logo'.`

How do I import a JSON object with object destructuring?

Note that this works fine:

```
import branding from '@src/config/branding.json' // branding.logo to get logo
```

I have JSON modules declared:

```
declare module '*.json' {
    const value: any
    export default value
}
```

branding.json:

```
{
  "logo": "https://apiendpointurl.com/logo.svg",
}
```

tsconfig has `"resolveJsonModule": true, "esModuleInterop": true`

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `declare module '*.json'` version you are specifying that all files ending in `*.json` will have a default `any` export.

You can use the `"resolveJsonModule": true` option in tsconfig to tell compiler you want it to resolve json modules. If you do this the `declare module '*.json'` for all `json` files that are found on disk and you will be able to import them with full typings.

Comment: I have `"resolveJsonModule": true, "esModuleInterop": true` in the tsconfig. I am starting to think it is an issue with the Vetur extension. Testing it in a .ts file, importing works with object destructuring without any issues.